# Orbeon - File not found at Zip and Unzip

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to change an Excel document in Orbeon Forms. Basically I try to get [this](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/898611/revisions) example working.

Unlikely I meet the problem that the `oxf:zip` / `oxf:unzip` operations fail because of a "File not found exception". So the file which the unzip-operation produces is not available for the zip-operation anymore. Any XSLT-Transformation is able to read the content of those files. What could be the issue?

Basics: I use Tomcat 7 with Orbeon 2016.1

Message:

> |C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%207.0\temp\upload_519c5622_1566e996c49__8000_00000002.tmp
>   (Th| |e system cannot find the path specified)

Reduced source code:

```
<p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
          xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">

    <p:param type="input" name="instance"/>
    <p:param type="output" name="data"/>

    <!-- Read .xlsx file -->
    <p:processor name="oxf:url-generator">
        <p:input name="config" transform="oxf:xslt" href="#instance">
            <config xsl:version="2.0">
                <url>--any excel file --</url>
                <content-type>multipart/x-zip</content-type>
                <cache-control><use-local-cache>false</use-local-cache></cache-control>
            </config>
        </p:input>
        <p:output name="data" id="zip"/>
    </p:processor>

    <!-- Unzip file -->
    <p:processor name="oxf:unzip">
        <p:input name="data" href="#zip"/>
        <p:output name="data" id="zip-file-list"/>
    </p:processor>

    <!-- Zip stuff back -->
     <p:processor name="oxf:zip">
        <p:input name="data" href="#zip-file-list"/>
        <p:output name="data" id="new-zip" ref="data"/>
    </p:processor>

</p:config>
```

Comment: I am trying this and it works for me: I can download the resulting zip without problems. I am using Orbeon Forms 2016.1. Also, I don't have spaces in directory names: I wonder if this could be part of the issue. What happens if you tell Tomcat to store temp files in another location? See also http://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads.

Comment: Yes, that's it. For testing, I renamed my java.io.tempdir to "C:/temp/" and it works fine.

Comment: Great to hear this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this as an answer as Denis has confirmed in comments above that the issue is related to the presence of spaces in the path to the temporary directory. Setting `java.io.tempdir` to point to a path without spaces fixes the issue.

I also managed to make the example work in a setup without spaces in the temporary directory path name.